# grpc-go: How to do Table Driven Tests for error cases

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, grpc, grpc-go

How to do Table Driven Tests for `grpc-go` when `errors.Is` test is impossible?

We use `errors.Is()` function from the errors package to check if a given error matches another specific error. This is especially useful during Table Driven Tests to validate if the returned error is the same as expected one:

```golang
var e1 = errors.New("Error 1")

e := mt.Errorf("adding more context: %w", e1)

if errors.Is(e, e1) { . . . } // Magical, it works
```

However, in `grpc-go`, `status.Errorf` is normally used to return error, and because it is [not supporting error wrapping](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/3616):

> by discarding the error, it makes errors.Is tests impossible to use

The suggestion/conclusion of that thread is to *"check the context directly"*, however, that approach is so brittle and easy to break that even the implementation changes a tiny bit, my test will break. This is the least acceptable solution.

So, how to do Table Driven Tests for `grpc-go` when `errors.Is` test is impossible?

Comment: How are table-driven tests relevant to the problem you seem to be facing?

Comment: I just test the error message:)

Comment: _"How are table-driven tests relevant to the problem you seem to be facing?"_ @jub0bs, to _"do Table Driven Tests for error cases"_, you need to save/provide the expected error message, and `errors.Is` is the best method to check for error matches.

Comment: @xpt Would you not use `errors.Is` if you weren't writing tests in a table-driven fashion? The table-driven aspect just seems like a distraction, here.

Comment: @jub0bs, I don't quite understand what you were asking because of the double negatives question, but I always do Table Driven Tests, and I always use `errors.Is` where ever possible to avoid the brittleness described in OP.